# Can't write into a video file . Video file is not creating

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I was just trying to read frames from a file and rewriting it into a new file using opencv 3.4.5 in python. But it fails to create the video file .

```
import cv2
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('movie.mov')
success,image = vidcap.read()
height, width, channels = image.shape
print(channels)
video=cv2.VideoWriter('video.avi',-1,1,(width,height))
count = 0
images = []
while success:
    images.append(image)
    success,image = vidcap.read()
    print('Read a new frame: ', success)
    count += 1
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
print(count,len(images))
for i in images:
    video.write(i)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video.release()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the way you declare the `writer`.

```
fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
size = (int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)),int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))
fourcc = int(cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('X','V','I','D')) # XVID codecs

writer = cv2.VideoWriter("new.avi", fourcc, fps, size)
```